# Babel LDF -- ensuring correct font encoding

Tags: babel

I would like to implement a modern Babel language definition file (LDF) for Macedonian, as the present one does not support XeTeX/LuaTeX (if Unicode is used).

In order for Macedonian to work properly, either

- `fontenc` with `T2A`, or
- `fontspec`

should be used.

My question is: how can I, within `macedonian.ldf`, make sure that the above condition is satisfied?  Is it even the LDF's responsibility to ensure that a correct font encoding is loaded?

Comment: Maybe a look at `babel-bulgarian` can help you: https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-bulgarian

Comment: you may need the T2A encoding for pdftex (which you could switch to without using fontenc, actually) but you only need fontspec to select a font, xelatex/luatex have the right encoding by default anyway. It's presumably the user's choice to select a font so I think there is not much to be done about encodings in that case.

Comment: note that with luatex jou could use T2A and legacy fonts but not with xetex (hyphenation would be wrong if you do not use Unicode fonts)

Comment: Thank you.  @moewe: Is the approach used by `babel-bulgarian` (likewise by `babel-russian`) --- i.e., parsing `\cdp@list` --- completely error-free?

Comment: @d125q I don't know, sorry. I assume people would have complained by now if there had been serious problems with that approach. More I can't say...

Comment: cdp@list is a reliable list of declared input encodings (see its use in utf8.def in the base latex code) but I don't think you need to know declared encodings, just make choosing the language switch to T2A if using 8bit tex and TU if using unicode TeX  t2aenc.def will be loaded on the first use if not already loaded)